# Remove/Add References and Compile antique VB6 application using Powershell

Tags: powershell, dll, vb6

I've been given the task of researching whether one can use Powershell to automate the managing of References in VB6 application and then compile it's projects afterwards.

There are 3 projects. I requirement is to remove a specific reference in each project. Then, compile projects from bottom up (server > client > interface) and add reference back in along the way. (remove references, compile server.dll >add client reference to server.dll, compile client.dll > add interface reference to client.dll, compile interface.exe)

I'm thinking no, but I was still given the task of finding out for sure. Of course, where does one go to find this out? Why here of course, StackOverflow.

Comment: I cannot share the code (NDA), but we've done VB6 pre processing with Powershell, say managing versions, adding dlls that VB code depends on, unless I got you wrong. If I remember correctly most of those are just text files, so you edit them and compile after

Comment: Yes, good point: they are text files.

Answer (score 3):

References are stored in the project `.VBP` files which are just text files. A given reference takes up exactly one line of the file.

For example, here is a reference to DAO database components:

`Reference=*\G{00025E01-0000-0000-C000-000000000046}#5.0#0#C:\WINDOWS\SysWow64\dao360.dll#Microsoft DAO 3.6 Object Library`

The most important info is everything to the left of the path which contains the GUID (i.e., the unique identifier of the library, more or less). The filespec and description text are unimportant as VB6 will update that to whatever it finds in the registry for the referenced DLL.

An alternate form of reference is for GUI controls, such as:

`Object={BDC217C8-ED16-11CD-956C-0000C04E4C0A}#1.1#0; tabctl32.ocx`

which for whatever reason never seem to have a path anyway. Most likely you will not need to modify this type of reference, because it would almost certainly break forms in the project which rely on them.

So in your Powershell script, the key task would be to either add or remove the individual reference lines mentioned in the question. Unless you are using no form of binary compatibility, the GUID will remain stable. Therefore, you could essentially hardcode the strings you need to add/remove.

---

Aside from all that, its worth thinking through why you need to take this approach at all. Normally to build a VB6 solution it is totally unnecessary to add/remove references along the way. Also depending on your choice of deployment techniques, you are probably using either project or binary compatibility which tends to keep the references stable.

Lastly, I'll mention that there are existing tools such as [Kinook's Visual Build Pro](http://www.kinook.com/VisBuildPro/) which already know how to build groups of VB6 projects and if using a 3rd party tool like that is an option, could save you a lot of work.

Comment: Plus 1 especially for the last part. Binary or project compatibility makes this problem go away. [This question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/179099/buildprocess-for-activex-com-vb6-enterprise-projects) has discussion of how to automate builds of groups of VB6 projects with some discussion of compatibility.